# Valor MAXIMO de uma coluna

Tags: sql

preciso mostrar somente a maior sequencia do produto, e não todas as sequencias

```
SELECT
    ITE.CODPROD,
    PRO.DESCRPROD,
    PAP.CODPROPARC,
    PAP.SEQUENCIA
FROM TGFITE ITE INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON(ITE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD)
                LEFT JOIN TGFVOA VOA ON(
                    VOA.CODPROD = ITE.CODPROD AND
                    VOA.CODVOL = ITE.CODVOL AND
                    ((ITE.CONTROLE IS NULL AND VOA.CONTROLE = ' ') OR (ITE.CONTROLE IS NOT NULL AND ITE.CONTROLE = VOA.CONTROLE)))
                    INNER JOIN TGFCAB CAB ON CAB.NUNOTA = ITE.NUNOTA 
                    LEFT JOIN TGFPAP PAP ON PAP.CODPROD = ITE.CODPROD
                    AND PAP.CODPARC =  CAB.CODPARC
WHERE
    ITE.NUNOTA = $P{NUNOTA}
ORDER BY 2
```

So o item destacado pode aparece uma vez

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se todas os valores são iguais para todas as `colunas` (com excessão da `coluna` sequencia), você pode escolher o projetar valor máximo de cada `coluna` (MAX).

Se os valores diferem, você pode fazer uma projeção o valor máximo. Então projetar a interseção (inner join) da sua projeção inicial com a projeção do valor máximo.

ex:

```
 inner join (select max(sequencia) from tgpap) x on (x.sequencia = pap.sequencia)
```

dica: a itentação da consulta está errada.